# Buscar key dentro de collect Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

tengo la siguiente collect

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#874
  #items: array:5 [
    0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#878
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 1
        "tenencia" => "2235050"
        "clase" => 58
        "marca" => 153
      ]
    }
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#876
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 2
        "tenencia" => "2235051"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => 153
      ]
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#858
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 3
        "tenencia" => "2235052"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => 153
      ]
    }
    3 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#856
      #items: array:11 [
        "no" => 4
        "tenencia" => "2235053"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => 153        
      ]
    }
    4 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#850
      #items: array:12 [
        "no" => 5
        "tenencia" => "2235054"
        "clase" => 59
        "marca" => "200"
        "error" => array:1 [
          0 => array:3 [
            "tenencia" => "2235054"
            "marca" => "200"
            "error" => "marca 200 no se encontro dentro del catalogo."
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

y quisiera obtener únicamente los elementos que tienen la key **error** estoy usando Laravel 5.7, es decir debería obtener el elemento 4, alguien sabe cómo hacer esto con **collects**?

Comment: Agregas tu consulta por favor?

Comment: Es que no es una consulta, solo es un collect que obtengo de un excel

Comment: Prueba filtrar tu relación con el método filter

Comment: Podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás obteniendo esos datos? Porque tienes una colección de varias colecciones, cada una con arreglo de un solo elemento y eso podría complicar un poco las cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `has()` de la siguiente manera:

```js
$errors = [];
foreach($collection as $item) {
  if($item->has('error')){
    array_push($errors, $item);
  }
}

return $errors;
```

Como puedes observar, se hace un array para guardar las colecciones que tengan el error. Usamos `has()` para `collection()`.

`has()` funciona como si fuera un `array_key_exists()`, pero en vez de trabajar con un `array()` trabaja con un `collection()`